# any tool/script to import a file listing / directory structure into a relational database?

Tags: windows, filesystems

...along with some basic metadata like dates and sizes

Should work on windows, otherwise DB and platform/language does not matter much.

Although I can and earlier have scripted stuff like this, I do not have the time now :-)

(What I am trying to accomplish is to analyse many files and folders, find regularities in the folder structure and enumerate every pattern that can be mapped to metadata in a content management system).

Edit:

For now I did a simple `dir /S /N /B` into a text file, split it using regular expressions and assembled every line into full path+parent dir+filename separated by tabs. Then I imported it into a database, assigning parent dir as foreign key.

Comment: Are you asking us to do this work for you? Because that's what it sounds like. If you can do this work but are short on time, pay someone to do it for you.

Comment: It seems like it is such a basic task, that I would expect that there were some already *existing* resources/scripts that could accomplish the task and yes, save me time.

Comment: And did you Google for those resources or scripts?

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to solve? A database seems like the wrong tool for this...

Comment: I've updated the question, hopefully it is more clear now

Answer (score 2):

This is really a "give me the codez" question, which we hate - but I hope I can help address the actual problem you're trying to solve, which I'm only guessing at.

While this ideally might be simple, I don't think that it's common. I certainly don't have a script like this lying around. **If I want to know what's on a drive, I use a dedicated tool like WinDirStat or TreeSize rather than play around writing my own database and analysis tools.**

And any implementation *would* be specific to the DB; at a minimum, you'd need a script to create the tables which is almost always DB specific, and the import script would likely also be DB specific. If I gave you something written in Erlang and it used Progress, would you find that useful at all?

Comment: Sorry, you may be right that it is too specific. I thought it might be common enough, so there might be some solution hiding somewhere, just "out of sight". BTW I am very familiar with the above-mentioned tools :-)